# Decomposing a flow to flows with support conditions?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold, $V$ be a vector field on $M$ and $\phi_t$ be the corresponding flow. 
Let $\{ U_i \}_{i = 1, \cdots n}$ be an open cover of $M$.
My question is that if it is possible to write $\phi_t$ as a composition
$\phi_t = \phi_{n,t} \circ \cdots \circ \phi_{1,t}$ such that $\phi_{i,t}$ is supported in $U_i$?
That is, $\phi_{i,t}$ is identify outside $U_i$.

More generally, if $M$ is just a smooth manifold, $V$ is a complete vector field, and $\{ U_i \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a locally finite open cover. Is there a decomposition 
$\phi_t = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \phi_{i,t}$ such that $\phi_{i,t}$ is supported in $U_i$?

Comment: Just to get the question right:
Isn't it the case that as $n\rightarrow \infty$, each vector lies in the tangent space of the point on the manifold? Wouldn't this mean that there is at least one decomposition where each vector is covered by one $U_i$ where the rest are assigned identity? Are there any other properties/regularization effects you are looking in such a decomposition? For instance, if we assume that the flow field is piecewise rigid, then it is possible to use much less charts with a higher dimensional parameterization.

Comment: I'm not asking any extra property other than the support condition for the the $\phi_{t,i}$'s. I'm simply asking how can one construct such a decomposition? Also, I'm not sure why we can take $n \rightarrow \infty$?